# SerialPort.Read() no se acaba

Tags: vb.net

Estoy tratando de conocer la posición de un motor por un puerto COM gracias al método `Read(Byte(), Int32, Int32)`

Cualquiera sea el puerto serie, cuando trato de leer con `SerialPort.Read(buffer,offset,length)`, nunca termina de devolver.

Este método lee varios bytes del búfer de entrada de SerialPort y los escribe en una matriz de bytes en la posición de desplazamiento especificada. No sé si esto es porque no hay suficientes datos o por otra razón. Luego, se cierra el programa.

¿Es un problema con el driver?

He leido en [este vínculo de msdn.microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) que

> El método `Read` devuelve cero únicamente después de alcanzar el final de la secuencia. De lo contrario, `Read` siempre lee al menos un byte de la secuencia antes de devolver. **Si no hay datos disponibles en la secuencia tras una llamada a Read, el método se bloqueará hasta que pueda devolverse por lo menos un byte de datos.**

Tengo que saber dónde está este motor para moverlo cuando muevo una cámara que está en otro puerto COM, y utilizarlo con un temporizador. Pienso que es esto lo que bloquea al programa, pero no estoy seguro.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para conocer su posición sin bloquear al programa? ¿Tengo que utilizar `Read()` solamente cuando muevo la cámara?

Answer (score 1):

Si el motor es capaz de enviar información al puerto serie cuando se mueve, puedes usar el evento SerialPort.DataReceived para obtener la información del puerto serie.

Encontraras un ejemplo en el enlace siguiente.

[SerialPort.DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx)

Ten presente que se ejecuta en un thread distinto del principal, si tienes que llamar a algun metodo de tu programa debes realizarlo usando .Invoke

Esta es la funcion que uso yo para leer datos recidibos de un lector RFID:

```
private void rs_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.rs.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            char[] n = new char[1];
            this.rs.Read(n, 0, 1);

            if (n[0] == 0x0a)
            {
            }
            else if (n[0] == 0x07)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Boton pulsado");
            }
            else if (n[0] == 0x1b)
            {
            }
            else if (n[0] == 0x02)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.TagRfid = this.rs.ReadLine();
                    if (this.Parent != null && this.DatosRecibidos != null)
                    {
                        this.Parent.Invoke(this.DatosRecibidos, new Object[] { this.TagRfid });
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    this.UltimError = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Si solo vas a leer el buffer del puerto, primero debes asegurarte que exista información pendiente, la propiedad **BytesToRead** te indicará si existe algo pendiente de leer, aunque segun que funciones Read a lo mejor no son capaces de leerla.

Yo usaría ReadByte usando algun bucle y verificaria uno a uno los bytes recibidos.

Answer (score 0):

Pues parece correcto que "no se acabe" hasta que haya información a devolver.
Asegurate de estar utilizando la configuracion correcta para la comunicación con tu dispositivo (numero de puerto, velocidad, etc.).
Y para comprobar la comunicacion y configuracion facilmente podrias utilizar alguna tool como Docklight (http://docklight.de/downloads/) o similares.